# Missing: KeyGroupBy?

Tags: dataset, associations

Especially in tree-structured data, keys and values, being two sides of the same coin, frequently interchange roles. The ability to aggregate by value but not by key upsets the balance.

How to improve on this workaround query - here defined only in operator form?

```
keyGroupBy[f_][expr_] :=  expr // AssociationMap[First[#] -> # &] // GroupBy[First /* f] // 
      Map[Values /* Association]
```

For example, given:

```
    data = Range[5] // AssociationMap[foo]

(* <|1 -> foo[1], 2 -> foo[2], 3 -> foo[3], 4 -> foo[4], 5 -> foo[5]|> *)
```

The desired output is:

```
data // keyGroupBy[PrimeQ]

(* <|False -> <|1 -> foo[1], 4 -> foo[4]|>, 
 True -> <|2 -> foo[2], 3 -> foo[3], 5 -> foo[5]|>|> *)
```

A fundamental constraint is that keys are transparent to functions accessing `Association`. Further, `Association` supports only data with unique keys. For example,  `GroupBy` nested in `AssociationMap` will drop all but the last key-value pair with a given key.

Comment: You can consider replacing `AssociationMap[First[#] -> # &]` by `Normal`.  Here's my right-to-left version: `Association /@ GroupBy[PrimeQ@*First] @ Normal[data]`

Comment: @Szabolcs, good, here's a version of your approach closer to my original expression: `data // Normal // GroupBy[First /* PrimeQ] // Map[Association]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Why not post an answer?  I can't find anything faster than that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I wasn't going for speed at all and it's a minimal modification.  Also, I'm not particularly confident in this area yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Szabolcs apparently declined to post an answer here is one of my own.  The best method appears to be the one that he proposed and I take no credit for it.  I do however offer a couple of inferior alternatives that might hopefully inspire some other approach.

#### Code

```
(* Original function for reference *)
keyGroupBy[f_][expr_] := 
 expr // AssociationMap[First[#] -> # &] // GroupBy[First /* f] // 
  Map[Values /* Association]

(* Szabolcs's recommendation *)
keyGroupBy2[f_][expr_] := Association /@ GroupBy[Normal@expr, f@*Keys]

(* reverse, GroupBy, and reverse again *)
keyGroupBy3[f_][expr_] := AssociationMap[Reverse] // # /@ GroupBy[#@expr, f] & 

(* manual Sow and Reap *)
keyGroupBy4[f_][expr_] :=
 Reap[
   AssociationMap[Sow[#, {f@Keys@#}] &, expr];,
   _,
   # -> Association[#2] &
 ][[2]]

(* method from mfvonh *)
keyGroupBy5[f_][expr_] := AssociationMap[expr] /@ GroupBy[Keys[expr], f]
```

#### Timings

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[
 {keyGroupBy, keyGroupBy2, keyGroupBy3, keyGroupBy4, keyGroupBy5}[PrimeQ] // Through,
 foo ~AssociationMap~ Range[#] &,
 2^Range[30],
 TimeConstraint -> 15
]
```

[image]

Obviously `keyGroupBy` and `keyGroupBy3` are slower than `keyGroupBy2` in this particular test.  `keyGroupBy4` appears to have some promise with larger sets but additional testing indicates that it remains several times slower than `keyGroupBy2`.

Comment: Another: `keyGroupBy5[f_][expr_] := AssociationMap[expr] /@ GroupBy[Keys[expr], f]`

Comment: @mfvonh Thanks! I included it in the timings.

Comment: A simplification of my version, `GroupBy[Normal[data], PrimeQ@*First, Association]`.  Also, thanks for posting!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thx for the analysis. Also Szabolcs x2, mfvonh, et al.

Answer (score 6):

The question of alternate implementations has already been answered nicely by Mr.Wizard.

I will however answer the question that is implicit in the title of the question: should `KeyGroupBy` exist in the language? I think the answer is clearly 'yes'.

Comment: That's good to hear.

Comment: KeyMapAt would also be useful.