# Association Subtotals with Lists as Keys

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I have the following `Association`:

```
as = <|{5, 2, 1} -> 3, {6, 1, 4} -> 9, {5, 1, 9} -> 12, {5, 2, 4} -> 6, {6, 2, 8} -> 10|>;
```

I want to total the values on the right side of the rules according to the middle values of the keys to get

> <|2 -> 19, 1 -> 21|>

The only way I know how to do this is to transform the `Association` to a `List`:

```
li = as /. (Association | Rule) -> List
```

> {{{5, 2, 1}, 3}, {{6, 1, 4}, 9}, {{5, 1, 9}, 12}, {{5, 2, 4}, 6}, {{6,
>   2, 8}, 10}}

```
li = GatherBy[li /. {{_, a_, _}, b_} :> {a, b}, First]
```

> {{{2, 3}, {2, 6}, {2, 10}}, {{1, 9}, {1, 12}}}

```
Association @ MapThread[Rule, {Map[#[[1, 1]] &, li], Total /@ Map[Last, li, {2}]}]
```

> <|2 -> 19, 1 -> 21|>

Is there a way to get this result without destroying the `Association` ?

Comment: Can use `keyGroupBy[#[[2]]&]` composed with `Total`: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59237/missing-keygroupby

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solutions based on `GroupBy` can be made a bit simpler by exploiting the fact that `as` itself can be used as a function, and I like the aesthetics of the curried form of [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html), where `Extract[{2}]` is equivalent to `Extract[#, {2}]&`:

```
In[1]:= GroupBy[Keys[as], Extract[{2}] -> as, Total]
Out[1]= <|2 -> 19, 1 -> 21|>
```

Comment: Impressive! How does the ` Extract[{2}] -> as` work?

Comment: First `Keys` gets all the keys from `as`, then you can `Extract` the second element from each key. This gives you the association `<|2 -> {{5, 2, 1}, {5, 2, 4}, {6, 2, 8}}, 1 -> {{6, 1, 4}, {5, 1, 9}}|>`, where `GroupBy` has already collected all the keys that share a common second element. The `→as` part effectively tells `GroupBy` to go back to the original association and treat the collected lists as keys (again), replacing `{5,2,1}` with `3`, `{6,1,4}` with `9` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
GroupBy[KeyValueMap[#[[2]] -> #2 &, as], First -> Last, Total]
```

> `<|2 -> 19, 1 -> 21|>`

Or shorter, per @Kuba:

```
Merge[Total]@KeyValueMap[#[[2]] -> #2 &, as]
```

Comment: `Merge[Total]` will be shorter. I'm not sure if KeyValueMap fits since it destroys association.

Comment: @Kuba Does it technically destroy the association? Or just map over the keys?

Comment: I have Version 10.0 which doesn't know `KeyValueMap`

Comment: @eldo Oops, introduced in 10.1...

Comment: @Kuba, ah, you're right. `KeyValueMap` returns a list for some insane reason.

Comment: or `Merge[Total]@MapAt[#[[2]] &, Normal@as, {All, 1}]`

Answer (score 2):

Not so compact

```
GroupBy[AssociationMap[Reverse][as], #[[2]] &, Total @* Keys]
```

Comment: It would be nice to have some kind of third argument for `KeyMap` to specify type of Merging.