# Group by multiple keys, merge at specific keys in dataset

Tags: dataset

I want to join associations in a dataset which share identical keys specified by the list `sameAt` and merge them by taking a `Mean` of keys specified by `meanAt` and taking `First` of the rest of keys. Below is a minimum example, not even doing what I really want (see later).

```
ds = {
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c1", "x" -> 1, "y" -> 7|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c2", "x" -> 2, "y" -> 8|>,
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c3", "x" -> 3, "y" -> 9|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c4", "x" -> 4, "y" -> 10|>,

   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c5", "x" -> 2, "y" -> 10|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c6", "x" -> 3, "y" -> 11|>,
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c7", "x" -> 4, "y" -> 12|>,
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c8", "x" -> 5, "y" -> 13|>
   };
sameAt = {"a", "b"}; (* associations with identical values at these keys should be merged *)
meanAt = {"x", "y"}; (* merging should be Mean at these keys, First at rest *)

Query[N @* Mean] /@ GatherBy[ds, (#a && #b) &]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> 0., "b" -> "b1", "c" -> 0.5 ("c1" + "c5"), "x" -> 1.5, "y" -> 8.5|>,
>  <|"a" -> 1., "b" -> "b1", "c" -> 0.5 ("c2" + "c6"), "x" -> 2.5, "y" -> 9.5|>,
>  <|"a" -> 0., "b" -> "b2", "c" -> 0.5 ("c3" + "c7"), "x" -> 3.5, "y" -> 10.5|>,
>  <|"a" -> 1., "b" -> "b2", "c" -> 0.5 ("c4" + "c8"), "x" -> 4.5, "y" -> 11.5|>}
> ```

As can be seen, my method is not general enough: had to manually specify grouping criterion `#a && #b &`; and averaging is not restricted for the keys `"x"` and `"y"`. In reality, I would like to make this work with:

- any number of keys in `sameAt` and `meanAt` (but see last point);
- any number of mergable "copies", not just two (so `JoinAcross` is no good);
- possibly specifying a different merging operator for each key, not just `First` and `Mean`;

---

A general approach, where each key has a specific aggregator defined:

```
sameAt = {"a", "b"};
op = <|"a" -> First, "b" -> First, "c" -> Last, "x" -> N@*Mean, "y" -> Mean|>; 
MapThread[Apply, {op, Merge[#, List]}] & /@ GatherBy[ds, Query[sameAt]]
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c5", "x" -> 1.5, "y" -> 17/2|>,
>  <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c6", "x" -> 2.5, "y" -> 19/2|>,
>  <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c7", "x" -> 3.5, "y" -> 21/2|>,
>  <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c8", "x" -> 4.5, "y" -> 23/2|>}
> ```

---

**QUESTION**

Can this be solved **elegantly** (being simpler than my above example) within the `Dataset`-framework, with a single `Query`? (If not, what is missing from the SQL-like Wolfram language that could make this work easily? Perhaps we can expect new functionality to be added, as it is hinted e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59290/89).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dataset[ds][GroupBy[Query[sameAt]], 
  Merge[Identity] /* 
   Query[Thread[meanAt -> Mean]~ Join~ 
     Thread[{"a", "b", "c"} -> First]]][Values]
```

> {<|a->0,b->b1,c->c1,x->3/2,y->17/2|>,
>   <|a->1,b->b1,c->c2,x->5/2,y->19/2|>,
>   <|a->0,b->b2,c->c3,x->7/2,y->21/2|>,
>   <|a->1,b->b2,c->c4,x->9/2,y->23/2|>}
>   . (* Normal'ed *)

Obvious limitation is having to specify keys complementary to `meanAt`. A 'KeyComplement' query would be great here.

**EDIT**

Here's an alternative using KeyDrop and post-Join:

```
ds[GroupBy[Query[sameAt]], 
  Merge[Identity] /* 
   Query[{meanAt /* Map[Mean], KeyDrop[meanAt] /* Map[First]} /* 
     Apply[Join]]][Values]
```

Both of these can be wrapped in a single `Query` op (here the grouping keys are dropped with `Values` as a separate op for clarity).

Merge will work with any number of `Association` arguments (I thought so did `JoinAcross`?)

I've already suggested to WRI to streamline the `Thread[meanAt -> Mean]` syntax to just `meanAt -> Mean` as composite keys can always be specified as `Key[{"d","e"}]-> f` (if such a key existed) to distinguish from mapping at multiple keys.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way:

```
ds // Query[
  GroupBy[#[[sameAt]]&] /* Values
, Transpose /* MapIndexed[#2[[1, 1]] /. {Alternatives@@meanAt -> N@Mean@#, _ -> First@#}&]
]

(*
  {<|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c1", "x" -> 1.5, "y" -> 8.5|>, 
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c2", "x" -> 2.5, "y" -> 9.5|>, 
   <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c3", "x" -> 3.5, "y" -> 10.5|>, 
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c4", "x" -> 4.5, "y" -> 11.5|>}
*)
```

Or, rephrased to use `GroupBy` directly:

```
GroupBy[ds
, #[[sameAt]]&
, Query[Transpose] /*
  MapIndexed[#2[[1, 1]] /. {Alternatives@@meanAt -> N@Mean@#, _ -> First@#}&]
] // Values
```

Answer (score 3):

```
GroupBy[ 
    ds, Lookup[sameAt], Merge[Identity]
] //  Query[Values, Thread[meanAt -> (List@*Total)]
] //  Map[First, #, {2}] &
```

Comment: Can't one really incorporate all the operations into one `Query`? Hard to believe that my task is not standard database/SQL operation that can be imitated with `Dataset`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I will try to squeeze it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Query[All, Join[Thread[Complement[Keys[ds][[1]], meanAt]->First], Thread[meanAt->Mean]]]@ 
 (Merge[Identity] /@ GatherBy[ds, (And@@(Function[{x},#[x]] /@ sameAt))&])
```

> {<|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c1", "x" -> 3/2, "y" -> 17/2|>,
>      <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c2", "x" -> 5/2, "y" -> 19/2|>,
>      <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c3", "x" -> 7/2, "y" -> 21/2|>,
>      <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c4", "x" -> 9/2, "y" -> 23/2|>}

Comment: My idea was that with `Query` and `Dataset` I can write code that I'll remember what it does years from now. This - while does the job - sadly is not particularly intuitive for me. +1 nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, I ended up using the following packaged functions:

- `associationMapAt`[$a$, {$key_1$ → $f_1$, $key_2$ → $f_2$, ...}]
  applies $f_i$ to the value of $key_i$ in association $a$. The values
  of keys not listed in the second argument are wrapped in `Identity`.
- `associationMapAt`[$a$, {$key_1$ → $f_1$, $key_2$ → $f_2$, ...},
  $def$] applies the default function $def$ to values of keys not
  listed in the second argument.
- `mergeByMapAt`[{$a_1$, $a_2$, ...}, $by$, $at$] gathers associations
  $a_i$ that share identical values of the keys listed in $by$ and
  merges each group to a single association by applying `Join` to
  matching keys, then it applies `Mean` to keys listed in $at$ and
  `First` to keys not listed in $at$.
- `mergeByMapAt`[$ds$, $by$ → $f$, $at$ → $g$, $def$] flattens nested
  lists in $ds$ then applies $f$ instead of `Join` when merging, $g$
  instead of `Mean` to keys listed in $at$ and $def$ instead of `First`
  to keys not listed in $at$.

Function definitions:

```
ClearAll[associationMapAt, mergeByMapAt];

associationMapAt[a_Association, f:_Rule|_RuleDelayed, def_:Identity] := 
   associationMapAt[a, {f}, def];
associationMapAt[a_Association, f:{(_Rule|_RuleDelayed)...}|_Association,
   def_: Identity] := AssociationMap[((# /. Append[Normal@f, _ -> def])@a@#) &, Keys@a];

mergeByMapAt[ds_List, by_] := 
  mergeByMapAt[ds, by -> Join, Union@Catenate[Keys /@ ds]];
mergeByMapAt[ds_List, by_, at_, def_: First] := 
  mergeByMapAt[ds, by -> Join, at -> Mean, def];
mergeByMapAt[ds_List, by_ -> f_, at_, def_: First] := 
  mergeByMapAt[ds, by -> f, at -> Mean, def];
mergeByMapAt[ds_List, by_, at_ -> g_, def_: First] := 
  mergeByMapAt[ds, by -> Join, at -> g, def];
mergeByMapAt[ds_List, by_ -> f_, at_ -> g_, def_: First] := Module[
   {gathered = GatherBy[Flatten@ds, Query@by]},
   associationMapAt[Merge[#, f], Thread[at -> g], def] & /@ gathered];
```

Original example:

```
ds = {
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c1", "x" -> 1, "y" -> 7|>,
 <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c2", "x" -> 2, "y" -> 8|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c3", "x" -> 3, "y" -> 9|>,
 <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c4", "x" -> 4, "y" -> 10|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c5", "x" -> 2, "y" -> 10|>,
 <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c6", "x" -> 3, "y" -> 11|>,
 <|"a" -> 0, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c7", "x" -> 4, "y" -> 12|>,
 <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c8", "x" -> 5, "y" -> 13|>};

sameBy = {"a", "b"}; (* merge associations sharing identical values at these keys *)
meanAt = {"x", "y"}; (* apply Mean to these keys at the end *)

mergeByMapAt[ds, sameBy, meanAt] // N
```

> ```
>    {
>     <|"a" -> 0., "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c1", "x" -> 1.5, "y" -> 8.5|>,
>     <|"a" -> 1., "b" -> "b1", "c" -> "c2", "x" -> 2.5, "y" -> 9.5|>,
>     <|"a" -> 0., "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c3", "x" -> 3.5, "y" -> 10.5|>,
>     <|"a" -> 1., "b" -> "b2", "c" -> "c4", "x" -> 4.5, "y" -> 11.5|>
>    }
> ```